# How to display highlight string in textView in android?

Tags: android, string, listview, textview

I am building an android application where I parse a set of data and display in listView. Now when a user searches a word in that data set I highlight that word of text-view.

Now the problem is when that search word is in beginning it is displayed as text-view is maxing line 1 but if it's last of the middle word of the paragraph is highlighted but I want to display that highlighted word in text view with max line 1.

Is there any way to adjust the string in text-view and display highlighted area.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use Spans. For example, you can highlight some text like this:

```
TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString("Hello World");        
spannable.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textview.setText(spannable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Already I have to tried in a fragment. hope this will help you.

```
final TextView sampleText =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_sample_text);
EditText ed_texthere =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_texthere);

final String fullText = sampleText.getText().toString();

ed_texthere.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        String typedText = charSequence.toString();
        if (typedText != null && !typedText.isEmpty()) {
            int startPos = fullText.toLowerCase(Locale.US).indexOf(typedText.toLowerCase(Locale.US));
            int endPos = startPos + typedText.length();
            if (startPos != -1) {
                Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(fullText);
                ColorStateList blueColor = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{}}, new int[]{Color.BLUE});
                TextAppearanceSpan highlightSpan = new TextAppearanceSpan(null, Typeface.BOLD, -1, blueColor, null);
                spannable.setSpan(highlightSpan, startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                sampleText.setText(spannable);
            } else {
                sampleText.setText(fullText);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```